# SQL IN statement with multiple conditions and 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have just learned IN and NOT IN statements in SQL. I understand statements like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.attribute IN
(SELECT table2.attribute FROM table2 WHERE attribute = condition);
```

My problem is I need to show 3 columns (from two different tables) using an IN (SELECT) statement with a 3rd table with a condition from that 3rd table only and another condition from one of the first two tables.

Example:
Show name(table1), class(table1), course(table2) where course LIKE "cosc%" (table 2) and grade = 'b' (table 3). I need to USE an IN statement.

My attempt:

```
SELECT stud.sname, stud.class, sec.course_num FROM stud, sec
WHERE sec.course_num LIKE 'COSC%'
AND stud.stno IN
(SELECT gr.student_number FROM gr WHERE gr.grade = 'B');
```

Table3 shares a domain with both table1 and table2. This query resulted in way too many rows, there are only 48 rows in one of these tables. I know how to do all the JOIN statements, I don't need that.

Comment: Please show the table definitions (`CREATE TABLE ...`) for each table.  Include the `foreign key` constraints to show how the tables are related.  You're missing `join` criteria between `stud` and `sec`.  That's the reason for the large number of rows in the result.  This generates a kind of cartesian product / cross join. Your `stud` table probably has a reference to the `sec` table.  If so, use that reference in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` or the `WHERE` clause in the form you used.  `JOIN  / ON` is preferable and less likely you'll forget the `join` criteria.

Comment: Include just a little sample data for each table, to clarify the contents and relationships.  Then indicate the result you expect, given that specific data.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, assuming `stud` refers to `sec`:

```
SELECT stud.sname, stud.class, sec.course_num
  FROM stud JOIN sec ON stud.sec_id = sec.id
 WHERE sec.course_num LIKE 'COSC%'
   AND stud.stno IN (
           SELECT gr.student_number FROM gr WHERE gr.grade = 'B'
       )
;
```

It's possible the logic needs to be adjusted and that other logic is missing.

We'll see when the question is updated with the requested detail.